# Does the order of the comparison conditions matter when using OR operators in an IF function?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, or-operator

I'm trying to get a better understanding of the conditions within an IF statement. When I change the order of the conditions I receive a TypeError of undefined.

I receive a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` when the order is changed to:

```
if (col === maze[row].length || row < 0 || col < 0 || row === maze.length) {
    return
}
```

**Does the order of the comparisons matter when using OR operators in an IF function? What is causing the `TypeError` when the order is written differently?**

Working code base:

```
const maze = [
  [' ', ' ', ' ', '*', ' ', ' ', ' '],
  ['*', '*', ' ', '*', ' ', '*', ' '],
  [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
  [' ', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', ' '],
  [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'e'],
];

const solve = (maze, row = 0, col = 0, path = "") => {

  if (row < 0 || col < 0 || row === maze.length || col === maze[row].length) {
    return
  }

  // Base case
  if (maze[row][col] === "e") {
    return console.log(`Solved at (${row}, ${col})! Path to exit: ${path}`)

    // General case
  } else if (maze[row][col] === "*") {
    return
  }

  // Marker
  maze[row][col] = "*"

  // Right
  solve(maze, row, col + 1, path.concat("R"))

  // Down
  solve(maze, row + 1, col, path.concat("D"))

  // Left
  solve(maze, row, col - 1, path.concat("L"))

  // Up
  solve(maze, row - 1, col, path.concat("U"))

  // Remove marker
  maze[row][col] = " "
}

console.log(solve(maze));
```

Comment: Yes, of course it does matter - js is evaluated from left to right, and the `||` operator does short-circuit.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Bergi. I read about operator precedence [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence). I'm still struggling to understand what is causing the TypeError when the order is written differently. Do you have any ideas on why the TypeError is occurring?

Comment: When first truthy condition occurs, rest of condition is not evaluated and true is returned. That's why you're not getting type error even if one of later conditions is invalid (you're trying to read length property of undefined). When you change order of conditions, and error causing condition is first, error will be thrown because invalid part will be evaluated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to keep two things in mind.

1. Javascript evaluation is from left to right.
2. The OR `||` operator is short circuiting. Which means the first time it encounters a true expression it "short-circuits" i.e. bypasses all other expressions and just returns a true. This is basic boolean algebra.

In regards to your doubt about the `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`, either of `maze[row]` or `maze` is undefined. On running your snippet it turns out to be that `maze[row]` is the culprit here. This might be because since you do a `row-1`, in your code row might become negative causing `maze[row]` to be undefined.

If you turn the order to

```
if (row < 0 || col < 0 || col === maze[row].length || row === maze.length) {
    return
  }
```

whenever `row < 0` i.e negative the OR operation short circuits all the other expressions. Hence `maze[row].length` is never evaluated and no undefined behaviour is encountered.

Comment: The `||` operator short-circuits when it encounters a `true` expression rather than a `false` expression. (Whereas the `&&` short-circuits on `false`.) It's also a good idea to swap `col === maze[row].length || row === maze.length` in case `row >= maze.length` to prevent another crash if `maze` changes.

Comment: ```This might be because since you do a row-1, in your code row might become negative causing maze[row] to be undefined.``` This specific sentence provided a great deal of light. Thank you!

Comment: @Sam thanks for pointing out that silly mistake. I have fixed it.

Answer (score 6):

> Does the order of the comparisons matter when using OR operators in IF statements?

Yes, in addition to operator precedence, you also need to look at [associativity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#Table) and [short-circuit evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-circuit_evaluation). The `||` operator has *left-to-right* associativity, meaning that it will evaluate the expressions from left-to-right. Short-circuit evaluation means that further logical conditions are ignored once the result is already known.

> What is causing the TypeError when the order is written differently?

Looking at your condition:

```js
col === maze[row].length || row < 0 || col < 0 || row === maze.length
```

Because the logical operations are evaluated from left-to-right, the first one to be evaluated is `col === maze[row].length`. When `row === maze.length`, then `col === maze[row].length` evaluates to `col === undefined.length`, which of course produces an error.

To fix this, you need to run this condition *after* first confirming that the index won't be out-of-bounds. A simple way to do this is:

```js
row < 0 || col < 0 || row === maze.length || col === maze[row].length
```

Now, if any of the first three conditions is `true`, then JavaScript doesn't bother evaluating the rest, since it already knows that the result is `true`. Because of this, it doesn't crash anymore.

(Keep in mind that `true || false === true`, so as soon as you see `true ||` then you don't even need to read the rest of the expression to know that the result will be `true`.)

---

Note that if you were using a language that *doesn't* use short-circuit evaluation, then you would instead have to use multiple `if` statements to run your conditions in the right order:

```js
if (row < 0 || col < 0 || row === maze.length) {
    return
}

if (col === maze[row].length) {
    return
}
```

I often find myself starting out writing code like this while I think through the order in which the checks need to happen, and then afterwards I simplify it down into a single expression.

---

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for the thoughtful answer. Your thoughts and the content in the associativity and short-circuit evaluation are very insightful.
```if (row < 0 || col < 0 || row === maze.length) {
      if (col === maze[row].length) {
          return
      }
  }``` <-- This row of code helps me to see clearly why the condition that contains ```maze[row]``` should be last.

Comment: "*The `||` operator has left-to-right associativity, meaning that it will evaluate the expressions from left-to-right.*" - no. Associativity is independent of evaluation order, which is always left-to-right.

Comment: @Beri, so essentially we should be listing conditions based on associativity and highest precedence from left to right.

Comment: @Bergi, good point, I just looked it up and I see what you mean. Looks like I'm getting "evaluate" mixed up with "applying operators to operand(s)". What's a correct way to word this without getting too technical for the OP?

Comment: @Sam Just omit "precedence" and "associativity", saying only that the operators are evaluated left-to-right and short-circuiting.